# Sinon stub ES6 exported function using Webpack, Babel, Chai (Vue CLI project)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babeljs, sinon, vue-cli

I am trying to mock following function (running fresh VueCLI based project)

foo.js:

```js
export const bar = () => 10
```

but as ES6 modules are exported readOnly, this is not simple. Following does not work

foo.spec.js:

```js
import * as testFooModule from './foo';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { expect } from 'chai';

it('Should be mocked but is not', () => {
  sinon.stub(testFooModule, 'bar').returns(1);
  // bar function is not stubbed, test fails
  expect(testFooModule.bar()).to.be.equal(1);
});
```

I am familiar with `babel-plugin-rewire`, but I was not able to get it working neither. I don't want to change foo.js file. How to mock bar function?

Thank you

- *Sinon ver: 7.2.2*
- *Vue Cli ver: 3.0.5*

Comment: If you console.log `testFooModule.bar` before the stubbing, do you get the func?

Comment: Yes, sure, there is no error in the code itself, I am struggling with this problem on many instances...I would love to see working test with babel-plugin-rewire used. It seems it is the correct way to make it work.

Comment: Your code works fine using `ts-node`, `TypeScript`